# Intervalo de confiança bootstrapped para os parametros de modelo GLMM

Tags: r, bootstrap-3

Estou com duvida para gerar um intervalo de confiança que me foi solicitado
quando é um GLMM

Normalmente se não fosse binomial faria por exemplo assim:

```
library(boot)
library(lme4)
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(100, -2,2),ind = gl(n = 10, k = 10))
dat$y <- 1 + 2 * dat$x + rnorm(10, 0, 1.2)[dat$ind] + rnorm(100, 0, 0.5)
m <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|ind), dat)

b_par <- bootMer(x = m, FUN = fixef, nsim = 200)
boot.ci(b_par, type = "perc", index = 1)
```

Mas quando o y é  binomial, não sei  como gerar os dat$y mencionados acima.

Obrigado

Comment: Olá Cleber, remova a tag `bootstrap-3`, pois é uma linguagem de programação. Para reproduzir o erro, disponibilize a base de dados, ou pelo menos, uma base com o mesmo comportamento que a sua.

Answer (score 2):

Eu rodei dessa forma:

```
(gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
              data = cbpp, family = binomial))
b_par <- bootMer(x = gm1, FUN = fixef, nsim = 50)
boot::boot.ci(b_par, type = "perc", index = 1)
```

que é um código exemplo da função `glmer` e funcionou para `binomial`.

Tente reduzir o número de simulações (como fiz aqui).